# How does angular custom directive initialize constructor parameters?

Tags: angular, directive

The following code snippet is part of custom directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appBasicDirective]'
})
export class BetterHighlightDirective implements OnInit {

  @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') backgroundColor = 'transparent';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue');
  }

  ......
```

since there's no explicit initialization of them, how does Angular initialize the constructor parameters under the hood? If I throw random parameters into it like:

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, 
  private foo: ElementRef, private bar: Renderer2) { }
```

it still works without any warning. What's the value of `foo` and `bar` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters in the component constructors are the [Dependency Injectors](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection). When the component is initialized, it creates an instance of each class or providers mentioned as the constructor parameters (DI's). So adding more params will simply create more instances of the class injected. Here `foo` and `bar` are nothing but the instances of `ElementRef` and `Renderer2` respectively.

Comment: Thanks! so in this case angular assigns values to parameters according to their data type right? no matter how many of them? here `foo` should be the same with `el` and `bar` with `renderer`?

Comment: Not same, they are the separate instances or references of the same class.